# how return json object when visits a url in webpack vue development project?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I create a project with `vue init webpack`,then put code

```
var users = [
       {"name" : "1"},
       {"name" : "2"},
       {"name" : "3"},
    ]
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  res.end( JSON.stringify(users));
})
```

in build/dev-server.js after line 59.

and I expect a json object returning when I visits `/users`  .but actually it is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>a
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vuehttp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

my problem is how I can serve the url and response json to client ?

Comment: put app.get(url...) before this middleware : connect-history-api-fallback will be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The webpack template has a `history api fallback` plugin](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/package.json#L30), which automatically serve your index page (usually `index.html`) when `/users` is not found on the server, so you may check whether your are *defining* and *visiting* `/users` correctly, or even remove the plugin and see if `/users` return `404`.

Answer (score -1):

How you serve that data dependes on what technology you're using on server side for example if you're using .net you could serve data trout an ApiController, in node you could use Express or any other middleware or JAX-RS in java.

In your client side exists different alternatives, I think that most common is to use [vue-resource plugin](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource), you need to install it and then use it as follows

```
  this.$http
   .get('/someUrl')
   .then((response) => {
      // success callback
    }, (error) => {
      // error callback
    });
```